# What is the word for multiple letters that behave like a single sound?

Tags: american-english

I'm trying to find a list of something like this:

```
ck
ph
kn
ch
sk
```

etc. Basically, they would be pronounceable and are often used to make up words. I think there is a term for this. Like 'ph' can be made in to 'phone'. 'Ch' can be made in to 'Check'.

Comment: Consonant Digraphs

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsaxonpublishers.hmhco.com%2FHA%2Fcorrelations%2Fpdf%2Fg%2FGr3Lesson4.pdf&ei=B8XOUNjcNpHjrAfHvYG4Cw&usg=AFQjCNGQ0E0RN9Jl-QfgjX5MHFnlhQGPFw&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.bmk

Comment: Let's not make it 'polygraph'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're called [digraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_%28orthography%29) -- consonant digraphs in your specific case.

Comment: is 'sch' (pronounced still as a single sound) still called a digraph or a trigraph? (e.g. in Schadenfreude)

Comment: @SF. **Trigraphs** chr, dge, tch, ... Polygraph Test: http://www.phonicsontheweb.com/digraphs.php ;)

Answer (score 13):

*Ch* and *ph* would be digraphs, but *sk* would be a [***blend***](http://www.phonicsontheweb.com/blends.php). The distinction depends on whether or not the two letters create an entirely new sound (the way "ph" makes the "f" sound, as in *phonics*), or if they blend together, retaining their root sound (like the "gr" in *grape*).

Therefore, the word *blend* has two blends, but the word *digraph* has a blend and a digraph.

*Kn* or *ck* (as in *knock*) are a bit unique, in that one of the two letters is silent. Nonethless, these are [still considered to be consonant digraphs](http://books.google.com/books?id=t11wKOyYYl4C&pg=PA250&dq=%22it%27s%20still%20considered%20a%20consonant%20digraph%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pNzOUJjTFpPzqwGKo4H4Aw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22it%27s%20still%20considered%20a%20consonant%20digraph%22&f=false).

Comment: In elementary school, in the 1970s, they were called "consonant clusters", but I'd imagine that "digraph" is a more technically correct term that our teachers didn't think were were ready for.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, a **phonogram** is a group of letters (or a single letter) that makes a single sound.  For example "igh" in high, "eigh" in sleigh, or "ough" in bought. [[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonogram_(linguistics))]

I believe English has at most 4 letters/sound.

**Summary:**

- Digraph = 2 letters combo with one sound
- Trigraph = 3 letters combo with one sound
- Quadgraph = 4 letters combo with one sound

.....

- Phonogram = 1-4 letter combo with one sound